# C# XML Deserializing Error (2,2)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

School gave me an XML document, and I have to display the information on a screen. As far as I know, Xml Deserialization would be the easiest/nicest solution.

I have this so far:

```
public static List<Project> ProjectListDeserialize(string path)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Project>));
    Stream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    return (List<Project>)serializer.Deserialize(filestream);
}

public static Projects ProjectsDeserialize(string path)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Projects));
    Stream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    return (Projects)serializer.Deserialize(filestream);
}
```

And this is how the XML document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>    
<Projects xmlns="http://www.pulse.nl/DynamicsAX/2009/DataSets" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Project ID ="1000.0001" CustomerID="1000">
        <Name>Project data key performance indicators</Name>
        <Status>WorkInProgress</Status>
        <StartDate>2011-01-01</StartDate>
        <ExpectedCompletionDate>2011-08-01</ExpectedCompletionDate>
        <CompletionDate xsi:nil="true" />
    </Project>
    <Project ID ="1000.0008" CustomerID="1000" ParentID="1000.0001">
        <Name>Implementation</Name>
        <Status>WaitListed</Status>
        <StartDate>2011-06-01</StartDate>
        <ExpectedCompletionDate>2011-08-01</ExpectedCompletionDate>
        <CompletionDate xsi:nil="true" />
    </Project>
</Projects>
```

Both methods are throwing the same exception:

```
<Projects xmlns='http://www.pulse.nl/DynamicsAX/2009/DataSets was not expected
```

How can I correctly deserialize the above xml? Any samples would be helpful!

Comment: did you define namespaces in project/s class definitions?

Comment: You should remove the xmlns from the Projects element.  or write a custom serializer. or use the xsd tool in the .NET SDK to generate C# classes that are compatible with that Xml format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the [default namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_undeclaration) for the XML document in the constructor of the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swxzdhc0.aspx):

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Projects), "http://www.pulse.nl/DynamicsAX/2009/DataSets");
```

**Related resources:**

- [XmlSerializer Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw0f5wee.aspx)
- [XML namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace)

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by combining both given answers, thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is that you didn't specify the right namespace as an attribute for your `Project` class.

You can tell the XmlSerializer to ignore the namespaces during deserialization (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870293/can-i-make-xmlserializer-ignore-the-namespace-on-deserialization)).

Alternatively, you can set the appropriate namespace using the `XmlTypeAttribute`:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.pulse.nl/DynamicsAX/2009/DataSets")]
public class Project 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by combining both given answers, thankyou!