# How to use XmlReader with behavior of XmlTextReader with Namespaces = false

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I want to parse 'invalid' xml using a streaming xml parser.
I have two options

```
XmlReader.Create(...,
    new XmlReaderSettings() 
{ 
    CheckCharacters = false, 
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment, 
    ValidationFlags = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None,
    ValidationType = ValidationType.None 
}))
```

Second example

```
new XmlTextReader(...) { Namespaces = false, Normalization = false })
```

The first is failing on unrecognized namespaces which are presented in the xml: `'...' is an undeclared prefix.`

The second is failing on invalid characters: `XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character. Line ...`

Is there an option to combine both behaviors (`Namespaces = false` && `CheckCharacters = false`) so parsing will not fail on undefined namespaces and invalid characters?

Input "xml" cannot be changed as provided as is. It is also huge and cannot be loaded to the memory.

**Update**
Xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <item>
        <my_ns:id>123 _0x13_here_ dd</my_ns:id>
        <other_ns:value>ABC</other_ns:value>
    </item>
</x>
```

Where `_0x13_here_` is a `(char)'\x13'`
I was wrong, and using `CheckCharacters = false` not helping here. It allows to avoid exceptions on content like `&#x13;` only.

Comment: XML with undeclared namespace prefixes is not 'invalid', it's not well formed.  I don't think you'll have much luck with any parser reading it, really.  Disabling namespace support in `XmlTextReader` will just mean you get errors that `:` isn't allowed in names.

Comment: @CharlesMager I've added an example of the xml. `XmlTextReader { Namespaces = false }` is able to read an xml with that type of namespaces without exceptions.

Comment: Please look at my answer to the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339811/how-do-i-create-a-xmltextreader-that-ignores-namespaces-and-does-not-check-chara)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to combine:
- multiple root elements (ConformanceLevel.Fragment)
- undefined prefix (AddNamespace)

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings() {
    NameTable = new NameTable(),
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(settings.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("MyNamespace", "http://exemple.com");
var context = new XmlParserContext(null, nsmgr, null, XmlSpace.Default);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings, context );
```