# C# deserialize xml while ignoring namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have to load and deserialize an Xml file into an object. I can read the xml, get to the point where the object is described and parse the xml only from that part which is great, but there is a namespace declared in the root of the xml.

I don't understand why but when reading the xml, even though I read it from a given node, the xmlns attribute gets added to it, resulting in my program not being able to deserialize that into an object, due to the unexpected member.

My code:

```
public static SomeClass GetObjectFromXml (string path)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
        string wantedNodeContents = string.Empty;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "IWantThis")
            {
                wantedNodeContents = reader.ReadOuterXml();
                break;
            }
        }
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));
        System.IO.StringReader stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(wantedNodeContents);
        SomeClass loadedSomeClassXml = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as SomeClass;
        return loadedSomeClassXml;
    }
```

How could I get rid of the xmlns and deserialize the xml into an object?

Comment: It's added to the outer XML because some containing node has a [default namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) which, being a default, applies to your `<IWantThis>` node.  Since `ReadOuterXml()` is designed to not change the semantics of the XML being read, it has to add in a default namespace to the XML returned.

Comment: I see, so what approach could I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

1. The default namespace attribute is added to the string returned by `ReadOuterXml()` because `ReadOuterXml()` *is designed not to change the semantics of the returned XML*.  Apparently in your XML there is a [default namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting) applied to some parent node of `<IWantThis>` -- which, being a default namespace, recursively applies to `<IWantThis>` itself.  To retain this namespace membership, `ReadOuterXml()` must emit a default namespace as it writes out the nested XML.

   If you really want to completely ignore namespaces on XML, you need to create a custom `XmlReader`, e.g. as shown in

   - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/873281/3744182) to *[Can I make XmlSerializer ignore the namespace on deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/870293/3744182)* by [Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082/cheeso).
   - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47043927/3744182) to *[How do I create a XmlTextReader that ignores Namespaces and does not check characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28339811/3744182)* by [Alterant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7686473/alterant).
2. You need to construct an `XmlSerializer` for `SomeClass` whose expected root node is `<IWantThis>`.  You can do this using the [`XmlSerializer(Type, XmlRootAttribute)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer__ctor_System_Type_System_Xml_Serialization_XmlRootAttribute_) constructor, however, if you do, **you must statically cache and reuse the serializer to avoid a severe memory leak**, as explained in *[Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182)*.
3. You are creating a local copy `wantedNodeContents` of the element you want to deserialize, then re-parsing that local copy.  There is no need to do this, you can use [`XmlReader.ReadSubtree()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree?view=netcore-3.1) to deserialize just a portion of the XML.

Putting all these issues together, your `GetObjectFromXml()` could look like:

```
public static partial class XmlExtensions
{
    public static T GetObjectFromXml<T>(string path, string localName, string namespaceURI, bool ignoreNamespaces = false)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(path))
            return GetObjectFromXml<T>(textReader, localName, namespaceURI);
    }
    
    public static T GetObjectFromXml<T>(TextReader textReader, string localName, string namespaceURI, bool ignoreNamespaces = false)
    {
        using (var xmlReader = ignoreNamespaces ? new NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader(textReader) : XmlReader.Create(textReader))
            return GetObjectFromXml<T>(xmlReader, localName, namespaceURI);
    }
    
    public static T GetObjectFromXml<T>(XmlReader reader, string localName, string namespaceURI)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "IWantThis" && reader.NamespaceURI == namespaceURI)
            {
                var serializer = XmlSerializerFactory.Create(typeof(T), localName, namespaceURI);
                using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(subReader);
            }
        }
        // Or throw an exception?
        return default(T);
    }
}

// This class copied from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/873281/3744182
// To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870293/can-i-make-xmlserializer-ignore-the-namespace-on-deserialization
// By https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082/cheeso
// helper class to ignore namespaces when de-serializing
public class NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader(System.IO.TextReader reader): base(reader) { }

    public override string NamespaceURI { get { return ""; } }
}

public static class XmlSerializerFactory
{
    // To avoid a memory leak the serializer must be cached.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897145/memory-leak-using-streamreader-and-xmlserializer
    // This factory taken from 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128757/wrap-properties-with-cdata-section-xml-serialization-c-sharp/34138648#34138648

    readonly static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer> cache;
    readonly static object padlock;

    static XmlSerializerFactory()
    {
        padlock = new object();
        cache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string, string>, XmlSerializer>();
    }

    public static XmlSerializer Create(Type serializedType, string rootName, string rootNamespace)
    {
        if (serializedType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (rootName == null && rootNamespace == null)
            return new XmlSerializer(serializedType);
        lock (padlock)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            var key = Tuple.Create(serializedType, rootName, rootNamespace);
            if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out serializer))
            {
                cache[key] = serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializedType, new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = rootName, Namespace = rootNamespace });
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hJwiQA).

Answer (score 1):

XDocument provides you a bit of more flexibility at time of deserialize any XML. I had a similiar problem and it was resolve using the next snippet code:

```
///Type T must have a default constructor

private T XMLToObject (string pathXML)
{
   T myObjectParsedFromXML= default(T);

   LoadOptions loadOpt = LoadOptions.SetLineInfo;
   XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(pathXML , loadOpt);

   string namespaceXML = xmlDocument.Root.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace: namespaceXML); 
   
   XmlReader XMLreader = xmlDocument.CreateReader();

   myObjectParsedFromXML= (T)serializer.Deserialize(XMLreader);   
   
   return myObjectParsedFromXML;
}
```

In addition, XmlSerializer provides you a set of events for register any issue or error during serialization process:

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace: namespaceXML);
 
 serializer.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler((sender, args) =>
            {
                //Your code for manage the errors during serialization
            });

 serializer.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler((sender, args) =>
            {  
               //Your code for manage the errors during serialization  
            });
```

Comment: This seemed to almost work, but now the namespace just gets to the last node for me, again resulting in an exception.