# Deserializing child nodes outside of parent's namespace using XmlSerializer.Deserialize() in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have an application that uses namespaces to help deserialize objects stored in XML.  The XML namespace is also the C# namespace where the object resides.  For example, given the following XML snip:

```
<xml-config xmlns:app="MyAppNS">
  <app:Person>
    <Name>Bill</Name>
    <Car>
      <Make>Honda</Make>
      <Model>Accord</Model>
    </Car>
  </app:Person>

  <app:Person>
    <Name>Jane</Name>
    <Car>
      <Make>VW</Make>
      <Model>Jetta</Model>
    </Car>
  </app:Person>

  <app:Car>
    <Make>Audi</Make>
    <Model>A6</Model>
  </app:Car>
</xml-config>
```

The configuration is really just a random bag of objects.  As you can see, there is a mix of `Person` and `Car` objects at the top level.  I use the namespace to determine the object type at load time for proper deserialization.  Here is the code for loading the document:

```
public static void LoadFile(String file) {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(file);

    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    foreach (XmlNode child in root.ChildNodes) {
        if (child.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) {
            continue;
        }

        Object obj = LoadObject(child);
        // TODO handle object here...
    }
}

private static Object LoadObject(XmlNode node) {
    Object obj = null;

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    if ((node.Prefix != null) && (node.Prefix != "")) {
        str.Append(node.NamespaceURI).Append('.');
    }
    str.Append(node.LocalName);

    Assembly assy = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type type = assy.GetType(str.ToString());
    XmlSerializer serdes = new XmlSerializer(type);

    using (XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(node)) {
        obj = serdes.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

You many see the issue right away, but when this code is used, the resulting `Person` objects are empty, however there are no errors.  The only way to get the deserializer to populate the child elements is to use the same namespace for the child elements:

```
  <app:Person>
    <app:Name>Bill</app:Name>
    <app:Car>
      <app:Make>Honda</app:Make>
      <app:Model>Accord</app:Model>
    </app:Car>
  </app:Person>
```

The only other option I have tried is to use fully-qualified type names as the element name (no namespaces), however I haven't had any luck with that.  Is there a way to cause the deserializer to accept the non-prefixed children of the XML node?

Comment: Just for background, in the real implementation, the objects do not always share namespaces (i.e. `Person` and `Car` are not necessarily in the same namespace).  This causes problems for the serializer and my methods.

Comment: you can do it in LINQ2XML instead of deserializing it

Comment: @Anirudha can you please post an answer using the sample XML I provided?

Comment: what data do you want from the xml..a collection of person..i guess or is it something else

Comment: @Anirudha I need to handle objects as they are deserialized individually...  At the `// TODO` line preferably.  Of course, any sample solution that comes close would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a method to accomplish this, modifying the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870293/can-i-make-xmlserializer-ignore-the-namespace-on-deserialization).

I created a custom deserializer that replicates the namespace for the starting node:

```
public class CustomXmlNodeReader : XmlNodeReader {

    private String _namespace;

    public CustomXmlNodeReader(XmlNode node) : base(node) {
        _namespace = node.NamespaceURI;
    }

    public override String NamespaceURI {
        get { return _namespace; }
    }
}
```

Using this reader, I am able to load stored objects with the following:

```
using (XmlNodeReader reader = new CustomXmlNodeReader(node)) {
    obj = serdes.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I know this is a bit bad form for XML (forcing the application of a specific namespace), however it suits my needs quite nicely.  Answered here in case it helps anyone else.