# Why Can't I Deserialize This xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am currently trying to deserialize some XML in the following format:

```
<content:encoded>![CDATA[...
```

And I have an object which has a property which looks like:

```
[XmlElementAttribute("content")]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

However despite the XML always having a value the property in the code is always `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content` is a namespace in your example.  Your element name is actually `encoded` so you will need to use the attribute marking your property as such:

```
[XmlElement("encoded", Namespace => "custom-content-namespace")]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

Note that you will need to declare the namespace in your containing XML:

```
<content:encoded xmlns:content="custom-content-namespace">![CDATA[...
```

This also means any child nodes would be prefixed with the same namespace.  Not so much an issue for `CDATA` content, but just in case you have other elements you are trying to deserialize.

For a related questions to this, see [Deserializing child nodes outside of parent's namespace using XmlSerializer.Deserialize() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765837/deserializing-child-nodes-outside-of-parents-namespace-using-xmlserializer-dese)

Answer (score 3):

`content` is the namespace - `encoded` is the element name.  So your `XmlElementAttribute` should be:

```
[XmlElement(Name="encoded", Namespace="<whatever namespace 'content' refers to in your XML>")]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you both very much! saved me hours your both legends!