# Deserialising XML without a declaration or namespace in Silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

I've been landed with a feed of XML data that I need to deserialise into objects in a Silverlight (v5) application. The data looks like:

```
<AgentState>
  <agentName>jbloggs</agentName>
  <extension>12345</extension>
  <currentlyIn>TestStatus</currentlyIn>
</AgentState>
```

I've created a class at the Silverlight side, and I'm trying to get this XML - which, you'll notice, is missing a declaration and a namespace - into objects.

```
StringReader sr = null;
string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
sr = new StringReader(data);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (AgentState));
AgentState agent = (AgentState) xs.Deserialize(sr);
```

.. but this throws an error `an error in xml document (1,2)`, as it's missing the declaration. Even manually adding a dummy declaration gives further errors about missing namespaces.

I've found [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870293/can-i-make-xmlserializer-ignore-the-namespace-on-deserialization) questions about ignoring namespace/declarations in XML, but none of these seem to work in Silverlight.

Can anyone advise on the best way to get this XML deserialised into an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working using the following code - I'm not convinced it's the "right" way to do things, but it seems to work:

```
 string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);

 var document = XDocument.Parse(data);
 AgentState agent= (from c in document.Elements()
                        select new AgentState()
                                   {
                                       agentName = c.Element("agentName").Value,
                                       extension = c.Element("extension").Value,
                                       currentlyIn=c.Element("currentlyIn").Value
                                   }).Single();
```

Thanks for the advice, it got me on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
    public class AgentState
    {
        public string agentName { get; set; }
        public string extension { get; set; }
        public string currentlyIn { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = @"<AgentState>
                    <agentName>jbloggs</agentName>
                    <extension>12345</extension>
                    <currentlyIn>TestStatus</currentlyIn>
                </AgentState>";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AgentState));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(ms);
    }
```

Comment: There's no Encoding.ASCII in Silverlight :(

Comment: Edited, it works with UTF8 as well. Can you give us the exact string output? It sounds like that's the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering what issue you have with appending the xml declaration to the string.  This appears to work ok:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("AgentState")]
public class AgentState
{
    public string agentName {get; set;}
    public int extension {get; set;}
    public string currentlyIn {get; set;}
}

public void RunSerializer()
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer agent_serializer =
       new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(AgentState));

    string agent_state_text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\AgentState.xml");
    Console.WriteLine(agent_state_text + Environment.NewLine);
    string xml_agent_state = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + agent_state_text;
    Console.WriteLine(xml_agent_state + Environment.NewLine);

    AgentState agent_state = new AgentState();
    using(StringReader tx_reader = new StringReader(xml_agent_state))
    {
        if (tx_reader != null)
        {
            agent_state = (AgentState)agent_serializer.Deserialize(tx_reader);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(agent_state.agentName);
    Console.WriteLine(agent_state.extension);
    Console.WriteLine(agent_state.currentlyIn);
}
```

Output:

```
<AgentState>
  <agentName>jbloggs</agentName>
  <extension>12345</extension>
  <currentlyIn>TestStatus</currentlyIn>
</AgentState>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AgentState>
  <agentName>jbloggs</agentName>
  <extension>12345</extension>
  <currentlyIn>TestStatus</currentlyIn>
</AgentState>

jbloggs
12345
TestStatus
```

Comment: OK, I've tried this, but I get `System.InvalidOperationException: <AgentState xmlns=''> was not expected`

Comment: @KenD - Even when I change the AgentState.xml file to have `<AgentState xmlns=''>` it still seemed to work.  Could you post the full XML?