# Ignoring namespaces in XML deserialize

Tags: c#, xml

I want to deserialize XML into object. I have no controll what xml i'm reciving, and into what object I'm deserializing.

I tried this: [Can I make XmlSerializer ignore the namespace on deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870293/can-i-make-xmlserializer-ignore-the-namespace-on-deserialization) and it worked... almost.

my xml

```
    <request xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <a:ProfileInfo i:type="a:ProfileAndBSymbol">
        <a:BSymbol>_47</a:BSymbol>
        <a:ProfileSymbol>FAJNY</a:ProfileSymbol>
      </a:ProfileInfo>
    </request>
```

`a:ProfileInfo` works fine, but `i:type` thrown an exception. How to ignore `i:`?

exception is in Polish and it is like this:

> InvalidOperationException: type is invalid. name= ProfileAndBSymbol,
>   namespace=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Contracts

Comment: Could you share the details of the exception you get?

Comment: exception is in Polish... Is is like this: InvalidOperationException: type is invalid. name= ProfileAndBSymbol, namespace=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Contracts

Comment: try to take i:type as an attribute and not an xmlns

Comment: I am not making this xml; I just recive it like this.

Comment: The xml is not meeting the schema requirements.  The problem is with the people who generated the xml and didn't validate the xml against the schema.