# Ignore or redirect xmlns

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, autosar

I'm using `xsd` to generate classes from a schema.

**The schema is for version:** 3.2.3

When I try to deserialize a file from version `3.2.1` using this schema, I get an `InvalidOperationException` because the root node contains `xmlns="3.2.1"`.

If I change the root node to `xmlns="3.2.3"` it loads fine.

So the question is, is there a way to load the `3.2.1` file when my `xsd` generated classes are for the `3.2.3` schema? Preferrably something on the XmlSerializer (or XmlReaderSettings) that says to allow files with xmlns="3.2.1" or xmlns="3.2.2".

If it helps, this is for `AUTOSAR arxml` files.

Comment: Use the xsd tool and compare the c# classes between 3.2.1 and 3.2.3.  There is not one answer.  The schema changes and could be due to a correction, or parameter than is now requires and your xml is missing the parameter.  Using Beyond compare one the c# classes will give you the answer.  The solution may be to modify the c# classes so they work with both new and old version.

Comment: I suppose you could make a custom `XmlReader`, similar to `NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/873281) to [Can I make XmlSerializer ignore the namespace on deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/870293), that remaps the namespace `3.2.1` to `3.2.3`.  But there may be other changes to the schema that invalidate such a solution, agree with jdweng that you should compare the old and new auto-generated classes to see what else changed.