# C# xml serialization and deserialization with custom namespace

Tags: c#, .net

I have this xml here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsm:ValidatedMeteredData_15
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.strom.ch"
xmlns:rsm="http://www.strom.ch"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<rsm:ValidatedMeteredData_HeaderInformation>
    <rsm:HeaderVersion>1.0</rsm:HeaderVersion>
    <rsm:Sender>
        <rsm:ID>
            <rsm:EICID schemeAgencyID="305">12X-0000001416-E</rsm:EICID>
        </rsm:ID>
        <rsm:Role>MDR</rsm:Role>
    </rsm:Sender>
    <rsm:Receiver>
        <rsm:ID>
            <rsm:EICID schemeAgencyID="305">12X-0000001416-E</rsm:EICID>
        </rsm:ID>
        <rsm:Role>DEA</rsm:Role>
    </rsm:Receiver>
    ......
    <rsm:ConsumptionMeteringPoint>
</rsm:ValidatedMeteredData_15>
```

with this c# class as a model:

```
[XmlRoot("ValidatedMeteredData_15", Namespace = "http://www.strom.ch")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.strom.ch")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ValidatedMeteredDataHeaderInformation))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Sender))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Receiver))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ID))]
public class EdmMessdatenXmlModel {

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValidatedMeteredData_HeaderInformation")]
    public ValidatedMeteredDataHeaderInformation? ValidatedMeteredDataHeaderInformation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MeteringData")]
    public MeteringData? MeteringData { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string? Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "EICID")]
public class EICID {

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemeAgencyID")]
    public string SchemeAgencyID { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [XmlText]
    public string? Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ID")]
public class ID {

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EICID")]
    public EICID? EICID { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sender")]
public class Sender {

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public ID? ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Role")]
    public string? Role { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Receiver")]
public class Receiver {

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public ID? ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Role")]
    public string? Role { get; set; }
}
```

I need a model to serialize and deserialize it, but I'm not able to put the "rsm" namespace before all the tags, and even the header is wrong: not able to write xmlns:rms instead of xmlns. How can I solve the issue writing a right model? i tried adding "namespace" in each xml root but didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870293/can-i-make-xmlserializer-ignore-the-namespace-on-deserialization

Comment: dont want to ignore it, but generate  the outputfilw with it on it!

Comment: Is the space between `www.strom.ch` and `ValidatedMeteredData_1p5` (in the `xsi:schemaLocation` specification) intentional? It looks wrong

Comment: What you've posted isn't valid XML. If you choose to cut out XML, please ensure that what you've posted is valid. If using Visual Studio, one can use _Ctrl-C_ to copy the XML. Then add a class to your project, remove the class code. Then in VS menu, click _Edit_ => _Paste Special_ => _Paste XML As Classes_.

Comment: @Flydog57 yes it is. this is the xml accepted...

Comment: Your XML contains `......`? If so, you should start by fixing that. Next, read through the XML, and check that each opening tag has a corresponding closing tag. What you've posted doesn't.